# Java Unparseable date: America/Chicago Timezone

Tags: java, parsing, date

I'm having trouble with my app trying to parse a date with the America/Chicago timezone. I have reviewed a bunch of other ParseException questions, and I think I've gotten all the common gotchas with date parsing in Java. The following code works for all other date/times I've encountered, but all the dates with the America/Chicago timezone are for some reason unparseable.

I set the locale for the dateFormat, and that didn't matter. I checked that each of the other parts were fine, I removed invisible control characters, I re-typed the string to make sure no nefarious characters were copy/pasted in, yet it throws an exception every time.

Any thoughts?

```
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd k:mm:ss zzz ");
dateString = "Wed May 02 15:45:47 America/Chicago ";

try {
    entry.setDateTaken(dateFormat.parse(dateString));
}  catch (java.text.ParseException e) { }
```

I have my reasons for wanting to not go the Joda route, and this is a simple enough thing I shouldn't have to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *believe* the problem is that you're using Olson time zone IDs, and I don't *think* `SimpleDateFormat` supports parsing those. Certainly using your code I have the same problem with "Europe/London" so it's not specific to Chicago. Can you give any examples with that style of time zone identifier which *do* work?

Comment: Yes, when I use other TimeZone names it breaks as well. So, in SimpleDateFormat, when the documentation talks about time zones with names, it refers to (for example) "Pacific Standard Time", not the time zones in TimeZone? Thanks for helping me to realize this!